# Svelte - Modal window with dark background and appear/disappear animations

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svelte

I created this code in Svelte which will show a modal and remove it when the background is clicked, based on a native JavaScript implementation I wrote earlier.

In the *.svelte files, I put the focus on the code and components, the styles are not included so that the code won't be too long in total.
You can find the CSS stylesheet, as well as pure JS implementation in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/IamMusavaRibica/ba50f359e8034f60ceb7e85cd89c31a9)
You can also see the svelte in action in [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b4cf5cdc6c9341bb908126b54e0a9cec?version=4.2.10)

While reviewing the code, please avoid the missing accessibility features, general HTML/JS/CSS tips (such as setting meta viewport and `* {box-sizing: border-box}`) or similar. I would like only the parts related to this specific modal implementation reviewed. More specifically, what parts could be improved or done with a different approach, such that the final product looks the same to the end user. This is my first time using Svelte so I'd like to hear any feedback.

A few things I'm currently aware of:

- There is little to no room for customization currently (opposed to the `populate` argument in `addModal` function in the gist). I prefer not adding such options if later I could find out that the base could be written better.
- The svelte versions supports only one modal at a time while the pure JS supports multiple. This doesn't affect in any way, because I never really targeted to display multiple modals at the same time.

**App.svelte**

```
<script>
    import {onMount} from 'svelte';
    import Modal from './Modal.svelte';

    let modalDialogEl = null;
    $: showModal = false;

    function clearModals() {
        if (modalDialogEl) {
            modalDialogEl.style.setProperty('animation', 'modal-disappear 0.33s ease-out');
            modalDialogEl.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
                modalDialogEl.remove();
                modalDialogEl = null;
                showModal = false;
            });
        }
    }
</script>

<div id="overlay-container">
    {#if showModal}
        <Modal bind:modalDialogEl bind:showModal>
            <p style="text-align:center">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vitae turpis
                consectetur neque elementum posuere.
            </p>
        </Modal>
    {/if}
</div>

<button on:click={() => (showModal = true)}> show modal </button>
```

**Modal.svelte**

```
<script>
    import Backdrop from './Backdrop.svelte';

    let backdropSelfDestruct;
    function clearModals() {
        backdropSelfDestruct();
        if (modalDialogEl) {
            modalDialogEl.style.setProperty('animation', 'modal-disappear 0.33s ease-out');
            modalDialogEl.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
                modalDialogEl.remove();
                modalDialogEl = null;
                showModal = false;
            });
        }
    }

    export let modalDialogEl;
    export let showModal;
</script>

<Backdrop on:click bind:backdropSelfDestruct></Backdrop>

<!-- svelte-ignore a11y-click-events-have-key-events a11y-no-static-element-interactions -->
<div class="modal-layer" on:click|self={clearModals}>
    <div class="modal-dialog mobile-fullscreen" bind:this={modalDialogEl}>
        <slot>
            Unfortunatly, no content was provided :(
        </slot>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Backdrop.svelte**

```
<script>
    import {onMount} from "svelte";

    let backdropEl;  // undefined until the element is mounted
    onMount(() => {
        console.log('backdropEl mounted.', backdropEl);
        backdropEl.style.setProperty(
            'animation', 'backdrop-fadein 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) forwards'
        );
        backdropEl.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
            backdropEl.style.setProperty('opacity', '0.85');
            backdropEl.style.removeProperty('animation');
        }, {once: true});
    });

    export function backdropSelfDestruct() {
        backdropEl.style.setProperty('animation', 'backdrop-fadeout 0.33s ease-in-out');
        backdropEl.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
            backdropEl.remove();
        }, {once: true});
    }
</script>

<!-- svelte-ignore a11y-click-events-have-key-events a11y-no-static-element-interactions -->
<div class="backdrop" on:click bind:this={backdropEl}></div>
```